# Explaination for the code

Tags: c, strlen, unsigned-integer, size-t

The output for the code is 3? Please explain.According to me it should be 
5.After removing "unsigned" still i got the output as 3.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 void main(){
    unsigned int c=0;
    int len;
    char x[20]="abc";
    char y[20]="defgh";
     if((strlen(x)-strlen(y))>c)
         len=strlen(x);
     else
        len=strlen(y);
    printf("%d",len);

}
```

Comment: Why don't you try printing the value of `strlen(x) - strlen(y)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `size_t` is unsigned in `C`. So the comparison being negative yields a positive number. (sign extended bits of signed number yields a large value in unsigned case). Then that value is compared with `0` - being true it enters the first condition. Outputs 3.

Even if you remove unsigned from `C` that result of the `strlen` substraction yields a positive number much larger than 0. That's why you always get 3.

Answer (score 3):

> After removing "unsigned" still i got the output as 3.

It is unimportant whether the variable `c` is declared as unsigned or signed

```
unsigned int c=0;
```

The problem is that the standard function `strlen` returns an object of the type `size_t` that is by definition is unsigned type.

```
size_t strlen(const char *s);
```

So in this expression

```
strlen(x)-strlen(y)
```

the result is interpreted as unsigned integer value. As `strlen( x )` is less than `strlen( y )` then you will get a very big unsigned value or at least a non-zero positive value.

Instead you could write

```
 if( strlen(x) > strlen(y) )
     len=strlen(x);
 else
    len=strlen(y);
```

And it would be more correctly to declare the variable len as having the type `size_t`.

```
size_t len;
//...
printf("%zu\n",len);
        ^^^
```